# Default props in Vue 3 composition api are undefined (TS)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props, vue-typescript

If I don't pass a value, the prop is just `undefined`, instead of taking the default value.

For example `switchView` and `activeView`. I have defined the props like this:

```
interface Props {
  config: {
    switchView?: boolean;
    activeView?: number;
    urls: {
      someUrl: string;
    };
    labels?: {
      someLabels: string;
    };
  };
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  config: () => ({
    switchView: true,
    activeView: 0,
    urls: {
      someUrl: '',
    },
    labels: {
      someLabel: '',
    },
  }),
});
```

And in the parent component, I'm passing the prop config object like so:

```
const config = {
  urls: {
    someUrl: '/example',
  },
  labels: {
    someLabel: 'Example label',
  },
};
```

And in my Vue Dev Tools I only see the passed props, but none of the default values that I've set.
What am I doing wrong?

If I pass them in the config object, I get them as a prop. But I expect if I don't pass those optional values, then the defaults will take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Vue has a problem with nested props, more specifically, the parent config object is the problem.
By removing it it works fine.

```
interface Props {
  switchView?: boolean;
  activeView?: number;
  urls: {
    someUrl: string;
  };
  labels?: {
    someLabel: string;
  };
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  switchView: true,
  activeView: 0,
  urls: () => ({
    someUrl: '',
  }),
  labels: () => ({
    someLabel: '',
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when you use `switchView?: boolean` to declare the property in the interface. It basically means the `property` is optional in the interface.

So, JS does not care about it value, at the moment it only care about it's type enforcement to be applied or not. If it optional and you are not passing it or by mistake missed it.

JS never complain about it because it optional. If it is not optional. JS quickly complain 'switchView' is missing on the object.

TLDR version: It doesn't have any relation with its value. So if you do not pass it. It always take `undefined`

You need to use `withDefaults` when you are creating the `config`.
So that `config` variable go through the initialisation process and assigned the default value at the time of declaration.

Might be something like this

```
let config: Props = withDefaults({}) // so this return initial object with default value
// update the object
config.urls.someUrl = "/example";
config.labels.someLabel = "Example label";
```

In short your initialisation process is missing in between.